# ASP.NET Core EF Not Finding Navigation Property

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm making a survey app and have 3 domain models:

`ActivityItem` for each activity I want to ask about.

`ItemResponse` to tie together an `ActivityItem` and `Checklist`

`Checklist` to hold all the `ItemResponses`

I want to get the `Checklist`.`ItemResponse`.`ActivityItem`.`Name` in the view, but `ActivityItem` is always null despite the database having an ActivityItemId correctly filled. I just don't understand why the app can't `Include()` that table.

Here are snippets of my models:

`ActivityItem`

```
public class ActivityItem
{
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
```

`ItemResponse`

```
public class ItemResponse
{ 
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int ChecklistId { get; set; }
    public virtual Checklist Checklist { get; set; }
    public int ActivityItemId { get; set; }
    public virtual ActivityItem ActivityItem { get; set; }
```

`Checklist`

```
public class Checklist
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public ICollection<ItemResponse> ItemResponses { get; set; }
```

I'm grateful for any help pointing me in the right direction about why this doesn't work. Thanks!

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because your navigation property name is `ActivityItem` but you are calling `ActivityItems`. So full query should be as follows:

```
var checkList = await _context.Checklist.Include(c => c.ItemResponses)
                     .ThenInclude(ir => ir.ActivityItem).ToListAsync();
```

Comment: Weird. Thanks! That worked. When I `.ThenInclude(r => r.ActivityItem)', `ActivityItem` doesn't show up in the Intellisense list, but it worked in the view. Wonder why it didn't show up in intellisense. That's why I didn't try to select ActivityItem from the list: it wasn't there :)

Comment: Lol, well thanks again. I marked your response as the answer.